# C#: Non-blocking sleep

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm writing a small application for my Logitech G510 LCD keyboard and am experiencing a little problem. After drawing to my screen, I'd like my program to become idle and remain active as process, but without consuming any resources from my computer.

However, I need to open a Form whenever a certain event is raised. I believe `Thread.Sleep()` is not the best way to do that.

Here is what my code roughly looks like:

```
int main(){
    InitLCD();
    DrawStuff();

    Wait();
}

void HandleEvent(){
    //Create a Form if none exists
}

//Must be called before exiting
void OnExit()
{
    CloseLCD();
}
```

Could maybe a seperate thread  which cares for the event be a solution? If so, how?

EDIT:// The application is an invisible WinForm application. This means, no form is created upon start. Only when said event is raised, an actual form is created.

Comment: it is a Winform application right?

Comment: It is actually a "invisible" application. Meaning, there is no UI after execution, except if the event is raised, then a WinForm is created

Comment: how is program kept alive ? Until until int `Main()` exists or `Application.Run()`

Comment: What is the event you are waiting for?

Comment: Write it as a normal WinForms application, but keep the main form hidden until you need it, then Show() it. You don't have to worry about creating your own idle loop, because it's already built into the application.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman I will try that and see if it succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Logic This way :

```
public static class Program
    {
        private static AutoResetEvent waithandle = new AutoResetEvent(true);
        static void Main()
        {
            LCDClass lcd = new LCDClass();
            lcd.mid_event += LcdOnMidEvent;
            lcd.exit_event += LcdOnExitEvent;
            lcd.init();


            Thread thread = new Thread(lcd.DrawStuff);
            thread.Start(waithandle);
            waithandle.WaitOne();

        }

        private static void LcdOnExitEvent(object sendet, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            //lcd work finished
        }

        private static void LcdOnMidEvent(object sendet, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // handle event, create form
            Application.Run(new MyForm());
        }

    }

    internal class LCDClass
    {
        private AutoResetEvent waithandle;
        internal delegate void MyEventHandler(object sendet, EventArgs e);

        internal event MyEventHandler mid_event;

        protected virtual void OnMidEvent(object sendet)
        {
            MyEventHandler handler = mid_event;
            if (handler != null) handler(sendet, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        internal event MyEventHandler exit_event;

        protected virtual void OnExitEvent(object sendet)
        {
            MyEventHandler handler = exit_event;
            if (handler != null) handler(sendet, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public void init()
        {
        }

        public void DrawStuff(object state)
        {
            // do work here

            // raise event
            mid_event(this, null);

            //do more work

            // raise event
            exit_event(this, null);
            waithandle.Set();

        }

    }
```

Comment: What about memory usage? It looks pretty consuming, although I couldn't test it yet

Comment: not really! waithandle are specially designed for that purpose